# Error invalid_request when try to receive WNS access token

Tags: c#, visual-studio, uwp, win-universal-app, wns

As is mentioned in [official doc](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/windows/apps/hh465435.aspx#access_token_request) I am using the exact order of request building:

```
POST /accesstoken.srf HTTP/1.1
Host: login.live.com
grant_type: client_credentials
client_id:/here's my client id from dashboard/
client_secret: /here's my secret from dashboard/
scope: notify.windows.com
Cache-Control: no-cache
Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded
```

and I am getting:

**400 Bad Request**

```
Cache-Control → no-store
Connection → close
Content-Length → 76
Content-Type → application/json
Date → Fri, 01 Apr 2016 11:23:08 GMT
Pragma → no-cache
Server → Microsoft-IIS/8.5
X-Content-Type-Options → nosniff
X-WLID-Error → 0x8004101C

{
    "error": "invalid_request",
    "error_description": "Invalid request parameters"
}
```

I am using an online [request maker](http://requestmaker.com/), and have to mention that 2 days ago it was working perfect, I was receiving the token and expiration time as expected.

I created a new app on the store to try out new client_id and client_secret and still same problem, also tried from other PC with different external IP and no success. Is WNS a usual windows shity service or I am missing something?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems you are putting `grant_type`, `client_id`, `client_secret`, and `scope` as the `Header` of your request. But as it is said in the [official doc](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/windows/apps/hh465435.aspx#access_token_request):

> The cloud service submits these required parameters in the HTTP request body, using the "application/x-www-form-urlencoded" format. You must ensure that all parameters are URL encoded.

These parameters should in the HTTP request body and URL encoded. When using [Request Maker](http://requestmaker.com/), you needn't add any request header as the default `Content-Type` is `application/x-www-form-urlencoded`. And also please do note to use URL encoded `client_id` and `client_secret`. The request would like following:
[image]

**Request Headers Sent:**

```json
POST /accesstoken.srf HTTP/1.1
Host: login.live.com
Accept: */*
Content-Length: 210
Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded
```

**Response Headers:**

```json
Cache-Control: no-store
Pragma: no-cache
Content-Length: 436
Content-Type: application/json
Server: Microsoft-IIS/8.5
X-Content-Type-Options: nosniff
Date: Wed, 06 Apr 2016 09:28:04 GMT
Connection: close
```

**Response Body:**

```json
{"token_type":"bearer","access_token":"EgAaAQMAAAAEgAAAC4...y0yNTQ1NDU3MDAA","expires_in":86400}
```